# Java Removing Look and Feel

Tags: java, swing, look-and-feel

How can I remove any look and feel on my JFrame application to make the controls look like default windows controls ?

[Screenshot of what I'm looking for](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tqlsJ.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify the look and feel you want to use.  I personally prefer to default to the "system" look and feel, which defaults to the OS specific implementation (Windows on Windows)

```
EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Do this BEFORE you load any other UI elements

You should also have a look at [How to Set the Look and Feel](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html) for more details

Answer (score 0):

The class JFrame belongs to the Swing Framework (so what you are creating actually is a "Swing Application" not a "JFrame Application") and seeing that you attached the nimbus tag you seem to have activated the [Nimbus Look and Feel](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/nimbus.html). If you want to achieve a native look, you need to set the system look and feel (see MadProgrammers answer written in the meantime).

Answer (score 0):

You can customize the Look & Feel using

`UIManager.setLookAndFeel("path.to.lookAndFeel");`

Optionally, you can also retrieve the Look & Feel from the system your program is operating on:
`UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());`

I haven't tested it yet, but if the default Windows Look & Feel is what you want to achieve, I'd recommend trying 
`com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsClassicLookAndFeel`

Exceptions included, the full code would be

```
 try {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsClassicLookAndFeel");
    } 
    catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e) {
       // handle exception
    }
    catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
       // handle exception
    }
    catch (InstantiationException e) {
       // handle exception
    }
    catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
       // handle exception
    }
```

(In case the above doesn't work, you might want to check what's installed, using

`public static UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo[] getInstalledLookAndFeels()`)